# Ehcache stats not showing Hit/Miss count

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have a distributed EHcache setup and i have exposed Ehcache stats via JMX for debugging purpose.
While start the application, i set these config params:

```
CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(s).getCacheConfiguration().setTimeToLiveSeconds(timeToLive);
CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(s).getCacheConfiguration().setStatistics(enable);
```

And they are getting set as i as print cache configuration later in logs and it shows correct value.
But the problem is that Statistics shown in JMX donot have any info on total hits and miss. It just contains correct object count in cache.

If i enable Hibernate staistics, i am able to see all 2nd level hit and miss properly.

Am i missing any setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Did some analysis on this with following findings:

1. `CacheConfiguration.statistics()` and `CacheConfiguration.setStatistics()` have been deprecated. [ http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.8.4/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html ]. May be this explains the reason why these calls are not enabling stats.
2. Setting the statistics parameter in ehcache.xml resolves the issue.